# explain the coding in VBA

Tags: vba

```
    Dim fdg As FileDialog
    Set fdg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    fdg.Filters.Add "Text Documents", "*.dat", 1

    While fdg.Filters.Count > 1
        fdg.Filters.Delete 2
    Wend

    With fdg
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = "c:\"
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems    'onby be 1
                strSelectedFile = vrtSelectedItem
            Next vrtSelectedItem
        Else
        End If
    End With
    Set fd = Nothing
    If Not IsEmpty(strSelectedFile) Then
        Filenametxt = strSelectedFile
    End If
```

Comment: `im not going to work on macro just a small task on this as i don want to spend much time` I was planning on posting an answer but your this comment really stopped me from doing it. :) If you are keen on learning VBA then I am sure you can expect lot of help here :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems this piece of code allows user to open `*.dat` file and assigns `Filenametxt` variable by a path to the selected file.

But in my opinion you should learn that by yourself, not just ask us explain it to you.

Comment: im new to macro thats y could you help it out

Comment: I was 'new to macro' too, and I tried to understand how things goes by myself. Read articles about VBA if you really want to learn it

Comment: im not going to work on macro just a small task on this as i don want to spend much time im asking you all